# How does oraclize deal with chain reorg?

Tags: transactions, oracles, chain-reorganization

As title, does oraclize deal with the case where the query transaction and callback transaction are executed in different side chains?

I mean in this situation:

`A-B
  \
   B'->C->D->....'        canonical`

Can such case happen that the query transaction are executed in block `B` while the callback transaction are in block `B'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the application developer, you need to handle this yourself.  There's a little documentation [here](https://docs.provable.xyz/#ethereum-quick-start-the-query-id).

You send (and get returned) a `queryId`.  You should check that this is valid inside your `__callback()` function when it is called.

You need to do this anyway, as the callback is public and can be called by anyone - so it could be an attack vector by a malicious party.